# Erlang shell pretty print depth

Tags: shell, erlang

The erlang shell truncates long terms, for example:

```
6> lists:seq(1,1000).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
 23,24,25,26,27,28,29|...]
```

How do I make it not do that?  Or at least increase the depth before it truncates the term.  I know I could do something like...

```
io:format("~p~n",[lists:seq(1,1000)]).
```

... but I'd prefer to configure the shell to do what I want.

Comment: An alternative to `io:format(...)` is the shell built-in function `rp(Term)` which does exactly that.

Comment: @Adam  Thanks, please repost that as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

An alternative to `io:format("~p", [Term])` is the shell built in function `rp(Term)` which does exactly that.

Comment: @AdamLindberg- Where can I find docs for `rp/1`? Can I use it for console logging through chicagoboss.

Comment: @trex You can find the (sparse) documentation in the [`shell`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html) module. Since it is a built-in function for the shell only, you'd have to implement something similar on your own. [Take a look at how it is implemented behind the scenes](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/shell.erl#L998).

Comment: Ok, Will go through it. Thank you for response.

Comment: Note that Adam's link points to `maint`, which means it's not stable: [here's a link](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.3.2/lib/stdlib/src/shell.erl#L1000) to the `OTP-18.3.2` tag.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://ulf.wiger.net/weblog/2007/11/20/extending-the-erlang-shell-part-1/) on extending the Erlang shell seems to show how to do what you want, but it's a bit more in-depth than just changing a line in a config file. Your best bet is probably to use the `io:format("~p~n",[lists:seq(1,1000)]).` approach.