# Displaying long lists in the Erlang shell

Tags: erlang-shell

When I call functions that returns long lists or tuples in the Erlang shell, the lists gets truncated, displaying `...` at the end to indicate there is more elements that is not shown. How do I get the shell to display the entire list?

For example: when typing `code:module_info().`, the following is returned:

```
[{module,code},
 {exports,[{objfile_extension,0},
           {load_file,1},
           {load_abs,1},
           {load_abs,2},
           {load_binary,3},
           {load_native_partial,2},
           {load_native_sticky,3},
           {delete,1},
           {purge,1},
           {soft_purge,1},
           {get_object_code,1},
           {stop,0},
           {root_dir,0},
           {lib_dir,0},
           {lib_dir,1},
           {lib_dir,2},
           {compiler_dir,0},
           {priv_dir,1},
           {stick_dir,1},
           {unstick_dir,1},
           {stick_mod,1},
           {unstick_mod,1},
           {is_sticky,1},
           {set_path,...},
           {...}|...]},
 {attributes,[{vsn,[225576456026721604984939683025195514980]},
              {deprecated,[{rehash,0,next_major_release}]}]},
 {compile,[{options,[{outdir,"/net/isildur/ldisk/daily_build/19_prebuild_master-opu_o.2016-06-21_20/otp_src_19/lib/kernel/src/../ebin"},
                     {i,"/net/isildur/ldisk/daily_build/19_prebuild_master-opu_o.2016-06-21_20/otp_src_19/lib/kernel/src/../include"},
                     warnings_as_errors,debug_info]},
           {version,"6.0.3"},
           {source,"/net/isildur/ldisk/daily_build/19_prebuild_master-opu_o.2016-06-21_20/otp_src_19/lib/kernel/src/code.erl"}]},
 {md5,<<169,180,113,244,195,188,176,68,162,6,74,100,65,
        30,60,100>>}]
```

I would like the `{set_path,...}, {...}|...]},` to be expanded to display the entire list in the shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use built-in shell function `rp/1`, e.g:

```
 rp(code:module_info()).
```

`rp(Term)` is equivalent to `io:format("~p", [Term])` which will print what ever erlang-term you provide. See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434248/erlang-shell-pretty-print-depth) for more detail.